# Can you guys help me with this issues in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build.gradle

Error1:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\revik.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format

Error2:
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.18f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

[Here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmulh.png)

ill follow all tutorial from this https://youtu.be/gpaq5bAjya8 but when i tried to build the error happens

Comment: Seems like you're either missing a keystore file or the credentials you provided are not correct.

Comment: hi thanks for the comment ill tried diffrent version unity and it works maybe the version i use before its not compatible for the newest component, thanks in advance 